# Obtaining the input box within an ng-repeat for styling purposes

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to obtain the textbox that is assigned to data via a ng-repeat in order to validate data via javascript (e.g. if it is an E-mail etc).

The below is something similar i am working with:

```
 <input class="form-control" 
        ng-if="key.sch_input_type == 'text'" 
        type="vm.data[key.input_type]" 
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="vm.data[column_name]" 
        ng-change="vm.updateRecord(data)">
```

I am aware there is the angular validation library available to use but because of the way the code is currently, type is used for another purpose (in this case text) so i cannot set it to what I require and so I am doing it via Javascript using RegEx. i.e. if it is not email for example, the textbox should highlight red.

Is there a way I can obtain the textbox in question or a better way to do this?

Comment: html5 has build in validation attributes. You can use them to avoid writing javascript for validating data in input. You can visit this link for more info https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/

Comment: I should point out that the above code snippet is wrapped in an ng-repeat and there are many different types of validation I need to implement.